# how can I differentiate mongoDB query by value of req.params.id in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, mongodb-query, vuetify.js

what I am trying to do is,
set MongoDB query statement differently by req.params.id value.

I am trying to set a different query statement to get a log filtered log with period selection.
each req.params.id represent these following meaning.

| Key | meaning |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | today |
| 2 | last week |
| 3 | last month |
| 4 | last year |

The problem I encounter right now is, each query works fine individually.
but when I classify it with if-else then it doesn't work at all.
and even seemed not entering to if or else statement

weird thing is, when I selected a filtered option(for example today(which req.params.id = 1)
it gets into the router path.
and prints

```
Id Code is String
Id Code is : 1
```

but not 'I am here in 1'
I also tried

```
 if(req.params.id === 1) 
    if(req.params.id == 1)
```

both not work for me...

following is my code.

```
 router.get('/:id', async(req, res) => {


console.log('Id Code is ', typeof req.params.id)
console.log('Id Code is ', req.params.id)


let date_ob = new Date();   // current date 
let date = ("0" + date_ob.getDate()).slice(-2); // adjust 0 before single digit date
let month = ("0" + (date_ob.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2); // current month
let year = date_ob.getFullYear();   // current year
let hours = date_ob.getHours(); // current hours
let minutes = date_ob.getMinutes(); // current minutes
let seconds = date_ob.getSeconds(); // current seconds

const posts = await loadPostsCollection();
let successOrFailure;

if(req.params.id === 1){                      // just today         
    console.log('I am here in 1')
      
    successOrFailure = [
        { $group: {
            "_id": {
                "year": {$substr: [ "$createdAt", 0, 4 ]}, 
                "month": {$substr: [ "$createdAt", 5, 2 ]}, 
                "day": {$substr: [ "$createdAt", 8, 2 ]},
                "hour": {$substr: [ "$createdAt", 11, 2 ]},
                "minute": {$substr: [ "$createdAt", 14, 2 ]},
                "second": {$substr: [ "$createdAt", 17, 2 ]}
            },
            "success_count": {
            $sum: {
                $cond: [{$eq: ["$passCheck", "success"]},1,0]
            }
            },
            "failure_count": {
            $sum: {
                $cond: [ { $eq: ["$passCheck", "failure" ]},1,0]
            }
            }       
        }
    },
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "_id.failure_count": "$failure_count",
            "_id.success_count": "$success_count",
            "failure_count": "$$REMOVE",
            "success_count": "$$REMOVE"
        }
        },
        {$sort:{_id:1}},
        {$match:
            {
                "_id.year":`${year}`,
                "_id.month":`${month}`,
                "_id.day":`${date}`
            }
        }
    ];
}


else if(req.params.id === 2){          // last week
    console.log("I am here in 2")

    successOrFailure = [

        {
            $match: {
                'timestamp':{ 
                    $gte: new Date(new Date().getTime() - 86400000 * 7),        // 86400000 : 1 day
                    $lte: new Date() 
                }          
            }
        },
            { $group: {
            "_id": {
                "year": {$substr: [ "$createdAt", 0, 4 ]}, 
                "month": {$substr: [ "$createdAt", 5, 2 ]}, 
                "day": {$substr: [ "$createdAt", 8, 2 ]}
            },
            "success_count": {
            $sum: {
                $cond: [{$eq: ["$passCheck", "success"]},1,0]
            }
            },
            "failure_count": {
            $sum: {
                $cond: [ { $eq: ["$passCheck", "failure" ]},1,0]
            }
            }       
        }
    },
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "_id.timestamp": "$timestamp",
            "_id.failure_count": "$failure_count",
            "_id.success_count": "$success_count",
            "failure_count": "$$REMOVE",
            "success_count": "$$REMOVE"
        }
        },
        {$sort:{_id:1}},
    ];
}


else if(req.params.id === 3){            // last month
    console.log("I am here in 3")

    successOrFailure = [
        {
            $match: {
                'timestamp':{ 
                    $gte: new Date(new Date().getTime() - 86400000 * 30),        // 86400000 : 1 day
                    $lte: new Date() 
                }          
            }
        },
            { $group: {
            "_id": {
                "year": {$substr: [ "$createdAt", 0, 4 ]}, 
                "month": {$substr: [ "$createdAt", 5, 2 ]}, 
                "day": {$substr: [ "$createdAt", 8, 2 ]}
            },
            "success_count": {
            $sum: {
                $cond: [{$eq: ["$passCheck", "success"]},1,0]
            }
            },
            "failure_count": {
            $sum: {
                $cond: [ { $eq: ["$passCheck", "failure" ]},1,0]
            }
            }       
        }
    },
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "_id.timestamp": "$timestamp",
            "_id.failure_count": "$failure_count",
            "_id.success_count": "$success_count",
            "failure_count": "$$REMOVE",
            "success_count": "$$REMOVE"
        }
        },
        {$sort:{_id:1}},
    ];
}

else if(req.params.id === 4){              // last year
    console.log("I am here in 4")

    successOrFailure = [
        {
            $match: {
                'timestamp':{ 
                    $gte: new Date(new Date().getTime() - 86400000 * 365),        // 86400000 : 1 day
                    $lte: new Date() 
                }          
            }
        },
            { $group: {
            "_id": {
                "year": {$substr: [ "$createdAt", 0, 4 ]}, 
                "month": {$substr: [ "$createdAt", 5, 2 ]}, 
                "day": {$substr: [ "$createdAt", 8, 2 ]}
            },
            "success_count": {
            $sum: {
                $cond: [{$eq: ["$passCheck", "success"]},1,0]
            }
            },
            "failure_count": {
            $sum: {
                $cond: [ { $eq: ["$passCheck", "failure" ]},1,0]
            }
            }       
        }
    },
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "_id.timestamp": "$timestamp",
            "_id.failure_count": "$failure_count",
            "_id.success_count": "$success_count",
            "failure_count": "$$REMOVE",
            "success_count": "$$REMOVE"
        }
        },
        {$sort:{_id:1}},
    ];
}

res.send(
    await ([
        await posts.aggregate(successOrFailure).toArray()
    ])
);
});
```

======================================================

Home.vue

```
<script>
// @ is an alias to /src
import PostService from "../PostService";
export default {
  name: "PostComponent",

  data: () => ({
    posts:[],
    summary:[],
    recent_5_transactions:[],
    comboItem:[
      {
        name: 'today',
        id: 1
      },
      {
        name: 'last week',
        id: 2
      },
      {
        name: 'last month',
        id: 3
      },
      {
        name: 'last year',
        id: 4
      },
    ],


 ....



methods:{
 changeRoute(a) {
    //this.$router.push({path: a })
    console.log(a)
  },
openLink(link){
  window.open(link, '_blank');
},
openLink2(link){    
  this.$router.replace(link);    
},
async changeHandler(id){
  alert('haha : ' + id)
  
     
  try {
    this.posts = await PostService.get_dashboard_Posts_by_selection(id);
    this.chartData=[];
    this.chartData.push(["date", "success", "failure"]);        
    
    for(var i=0;i<Object.keys(this.posts[0]).length;i++){        
      this.chartData.push([`${this.posts[0][i]._id.year}-${this.posts[0][i]._id.month}-${this.posts[0][i]._id.day} ${this.posts[0][i]._id.hour}:${this.posts[0][i]._id.minute}:${this.posts[0][i]._id.second}`, this.posts[0][i]._id.success_count, this.posts[0][i]._id.failure_count])
    }        
  } catch (err) {
    this.error = err.message;
  }
}
```

======================

postService.js

```
// get transaction_logs posts
static get_dashboard_Posts_by_selection(option) {
  return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      console.log("selected Option = ", option)
      const res = await axios.get(url_dashboard+"/:"+ `${option}`);
      const data = res.data;
      resolve(
        data.map((post) => ({
          ...post,
          //createdAt: new Date(post.createdAt),
        }))
      );
    } catch (err) {
      reject(err);
    }
  });
```

=============================

post_dashboard.js

```
router.get('/', async(req, res) => {
const posts = await loadPostsCollection();
const successOrFailure = [
    { $group: {
        "_id": {
            "year": {$substr: [ "$createdAt", 0, 4 ]}, 
            "month": {$substr: [ "$createdAt", 5, 2 ]}, 
            "day": {$substr: [ "$createdAt", 8, 2 ]}
        },
        "success_count": {
           $sum: {
             $cond: [{$eq: ["$passCheck", "success"]},1,0]
           }
         },
         "failure_count": {
           $sum: {
             $cond: [ { $eq: ["$passCheck", "failure" ]},1,0]
           }
         }       
      }
   },
   {
       "$addFields": {
         "_id.failure_count": "$failure_count",
         "_id.success_count": "$success_count",
         "failure_count": "$$REMOVE",
         "success_count": "$$REMOVE"
       }
     },
    {$sort:{_id:1}}
];

const user_transaction = await loadPostsCollection();
const transaction_portion = [
    { 
            '$group' : 
            {
                '_id' : '$transactionLogs_docs.userId', 
                'count' : {'$sum' : 1} 
            }
    }
];


const device_count = await loadPostsCollection_device();
const count_device = [
    { $count: "myCount" }              
];


const user_count = await loadPostsCollection_users();
const count_user = [
    { $count: "myCount" }              
];

const count_transaction = [
    { $count: "myCount" }              
];


const max_min_avg_transaction_elapsedTime = [
    {$unwind : "$transactionLogs_docs"}, 
    {$group : {
            _id : null,
            "avg_elapsedTime" :{$avg :  "$transactionLogs_docs.elapsedTime"},   
            "max_elapsedTime" :{$max :  "$transactionLogs_docs.elapsedTime"},  
            "min_elapsedTime" :{$min :  "$transactionLogs_docs.elapsedTime"},  
        }
    }        
];

const get_recent_5_transactions = [
    {$sort : {'timestamp':-1} },
    {$project : {'createdAt' : 1, 'transactionLogs_docs.transactionType' : 1, 'max_temp' : 1 , 'transactionLogs_docs.auditFaceImg' : 1, 'transactionLogs_docs.userId' : 1}},
    {$limit : 5 }
];

const count_success_failure_transactions = [
    { 
        '$group' : 
        {
            '_id' : '$passCheck', 
            'count' : {'$sum' : 1} 
        }
    }          
];


res.send(
    await ([
        await posts.aggregate(successOrFailure).toArray(),
        await user_transaction.aggregate(transaction_portion).toArray(),
        await device_count.aggregate(count_device).toArray(),
        await user_count.aggregate(count_user).toArray(),
        await user_transaction.aggregate(count_transaction).toArray(),
        await user_transaction.aggregate(max_min_avg_transaction_elapsedTime).toArray(),
        await user_transaction.aggregate(get_recent_5_transactions).toArray(),
        await user_transaction.aggregate(count_success_failure_transactions).toArray()
    ])
);
});


router.get('/:id', async(req, res) => {


console.log('Id Code is ', typeof req.params.id)
console.log('Id Code is ', req.params.id)


let date_ob = new Date();   // current date 
let date = ("0" + date_ob.getDate()).slice(-2); // adjust 0 before single digit date
let month = ("0" + (date_ob.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2); // current month
let year = date_ob.getFullYear();   // current year
let hours = date_ob.getHours(); // current hours
let minutes = date_ob.getMinutes(); // current minutes
let seconds = date_ob.getSeconds(); // current seconds

const posts = await loadPostsCollection();
let successOrFailure;


switch(req.params.id){
    case 1:{
        console.log('I am here in 1')
        break;
    }
    case 2:{
        console.log('I am here in 2')
        break;
    }
    case 3:{
        console.log('I am here in 3')
        break;
    }
    case 4:{
        console.log('I am here in 4')
        break;
    }
    default:{
        console.log('nothing')
        break;
    }
}
/*
if(req.params.id == "1"){                      // just today         
    console.log('I am here in 1')
      
    successOrFailure = [
        { $group: {
            "_id": {
                "year": {$substr: [ "$createdAt", 0, 4 ]}, 
                "month": {$substr: [ "$createdAt", 5, 2 ]}, 
                "day": {$substr: [ "$createdAt", 8, 2 ]},
                "hour": {$substr: [ "$createdAt", 11, 2 ]},
                "minute": {$substr: [ "$createdAt", 14, 2 ]},
                "second": {$substr: [ "$createdAt", 17, 2 ]}
            },
            "success_count": {
            $sum: {
                $cond: [{$eq: ["$passCheck", "success"]},1,0]
            }
            },
            "failure_count": {
            $sum: {
                $cond: [ { $eq: ["$passCheck", "failure" ]},1,0]
            }
            }       
        }
    },
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "_id.failure_count": "$failure_count",
            "_id.success_count": "$success_count",
            "failure_count": "$$REMOVE",
            "success_count": "$$REMOVE"
        }
        },
        {$sort:{_id:1}},
        {$match:
            {
                "_id.year":`${year}`,
                "_id.month":`${month}`,
                "_id.day":`${date}`
            }
        }
    ];
}


else if(req.params.id === 2){          // last week
    console.log("I am here in 2")

    successOrFailure = [

        {
            $match: {
                'timestamp':{ 
                    $gte: new Date(new Date().getTime() - 86400000 * 7),        // 86400000 : 1 day
                    $lte: new Date() 
                }          
            }
        },
            { $group: {
            "_id": {
                "year": {$substr: [ "$createdAt", 0, 4 ]}, 
                "month": {$substr: [ "$createdAt", 5, 2 ]}, 
                "day": {$substr: [ "$createdAt", 8, 2 ]}
            },
            "success_count": {
            $sum: {
                $cond: [{$eq: ["$passCheck", "success"]},1,0]
            }
            },
            "failure_count": {
            $sum: {
                $cond: [ { $eq: ["$passCheck", "failure" ]},1,0]
            }
            }       
        }
    },
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "_id.timestamp": "$timestamp",
            "_id.failure_count": "$failure_count",
            "_id.success_count": "$success_count",
            "failure_count": "$$REMOVE",
            "success_count": "$$REMOVE"
        }
        },
        {$sort:{_id:1}},
    ];
}


else if(req.params.id === 3){            // last month
    console.log("I am here in 3")

    successOrFailure = [
        {
            $match: {
                'timestamp':{ 
                    $gte: new Date(new Date().getTime() - 86400000 * 30),        // 86400000 : 1 day
                    $lte: new Date() 
                }          
            }
        },
            { $group: {
            "_id": {
                "year": {$substr: [ "$createdAt", 0, 4 ]}, 
                "month": {$substr: [ "$createdAt", 5, 2 ]}, 
                "day": {$substr: [ "$createdAt", 8, 2 ]}
            },
            "success_count": {
            $sum: {
                $cond: [{$eq: ["$passCheck", "success"]},1,0]
            }
            },
            "failure_count": {
            $sum: {
                $cond: [ { $eq: ["$passCheck", "failure" ]},1,0]
            }
            }       
        }
    },
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "_id.timestamp": "$timestamp",
            "_id.failure_count": "$failure_count",
            "_id.success_count": "$success_count",
            "failure_count": "$$REMOVE",
            "success_count": "$$REMOVE"
        }
        },
        {$sort:{_id:1}},
    ];
}

else if(req.params.id === 4){              // last year
    console.log("I am here in 4")

    successOrFailure = [
        {
            $match: {
                'timestamp':{ 
                    $gte: new Date(new Date().getTime() - 86400000 * 365),        // 86400000 : 1 day
                    $lte: new Date() 
                }          
            }
        },
            { $group: {
            "_id": {
                "year": {$substr: [ "$createdAt", 0, 4 ]}, 
                "month": {$substr: [ "$createdAt", 5, 2 ]}, 
                "day": {$substr: [ "$createdAt", 8, 2 ]}
            },
            "success_count": {
            $sum: {
                $cond: [{$eq: ["$passCheck", "success"]},1,0]
            }
            },
            "failure_count": {
            $sum: {
                $cond: [ { $eq: ["$passCheck", "failure" ]},1,0]
            }
            }       
        }
    },
    {
        "$addFields": {
            "_id.timestamp": "$timestamp",
            "_id.failure_count": "$failure_count",
            "_id.success_count": "$success_count",
            "failure_count": "$$REMOVE",
            "success_count": "$$REMOVE"
        }
        },
        {$sort:{_id:1}},
    ];
}
*/

res.send(
    await ([
        await posts.aggregate(successOrFailure).toArray()
    ])
);
});
```

above is partial related part's code.
select option from combobox each item has mapped defined Id digit

order is Client side [Home.vue -> PostService.js]
-> Server(DB related) side[posts_dashboard.js]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller, you need to check it like this

```
if(req.params.id == '1')
```

In `postService.js`
**Update** this line

```
const res = await axios.get(url_dashboard+"/:"+ `${option}`);
```

**To** this

```
const res = await axios.get(url_dashboard+"/"+ `${option}`);
```

Just remove the `:` there. This will fix the issue

Comment: both not working :S 
Have no clue...why it doesn't work :(

Comment: `==` will not strict compare the types and it will work

Comment: still not entering that if statement :'(

Comment: How are you passing the parameter ? Can you paste the URL here ?

Comment: You don't need to add `:` in the URL. I can see you are having this in the console `Id Code is : 1` which is incorrect . This means you are adding an additional `:` in the URL which you should not

Comment: added related codes above in main question text.
still stuck in this problem :( @Md.Reyad Hossain

Comment: Thank you for providing the relevant code. As I told, the issue is with the `:` which lies in postService.js file. Check the updated answer. Let me know if I were able to help you :)

Comment: you really saved my day thank you so much :)